# How to get new record in SQL Server or C# by checking if id exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How to get the record in database by checking that the `OrgId` is not in less than `TransactionDate`.

Here it my current code in SQL. But I want to apply it in a C# LINQ query after I find the solution in SQL Server.

```
select 
    refno, OrgId, typeCode, fullnames 
from 
    Transactions 
where 
    TransactionDate >= '01/06/2015'
    and OrgId not in (select OrgId from Transactions 
                      where TransactionDate < '01/06/2015')
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  `OrgId` is a presumably number.  How can it be less than `TransactionDate`, which is presumably a date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry.  I meant TransactionDate less than a gaven date. As you see in the code. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your query and what it does but I can give you the linq for what you have there. Depending on you data structure it might be that TransactionDate >= date already implies the second condition.

```
var date = new DateTime("01/06/2015");
var result = Transactions.Where(x => x.TransactionDate >= date && 
    !Transactions.Where(y => y.TransactionDate < date)
            .Select(y => y.OrgId).Contains(x.OrgId))
        .Select(x => new {
            refno = x.refno,
            OrgId = x.OrgId,
            typeCode = x.typeCode,
            fullnames = x.fullnames
        });
```

This is also selected into an anonymous type, I would probably look at creating a class for the result to be selected into.

```
public class Result{
    public int refno { get; set; }
    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public string typeCode { get; set; }
    public string fullnames { get; set; }
}

var date = new DateTime("01/06/2015");
var result = Transactions.Where(x => x.TransactionDate >= date && 
    !Transactions.Where(y => y.TransactionDate < date)
            .Select(y => y.OrgId).Contains(x.OrgId))
        .Select(x => new Result(){
            refno = x.refno,
            OrgId = x.OrgId,
            typeCode = x.typeCode,
            fullnames = x.fullnames
        });
```

Comment: Thank you it works. You helped me thank you very much. God Bless. I was stack really I have been trying to solve this problem in the past 3 weeks and I was looking for the help online no one gave me the correct answer. But yesterday I decided to come up with an sql query at least may be someone can understand what I want. And you gave me exactly what I want thank you.